# Accessing page from LAYOUTS, how to turn off custom errors

Tags: custom, web-config, layouts

I have a custom page that I access through myspaddress/_layouts/folder/default.aspx.

Great. Awesome. However, lately it's showing a runtime error.

All I can get though is the standard "Server Error in '/' Application." page. I've tried turning off custom errors in the web.config in my solution, in the LAYOUTS folder, and in a desperate attempt - every web config I have in IIS. ALAS... still no luck.

If anyone knows the secret to getting the underlying error to display instead of the friendly page, I'd be much obliged!

Comment: I missed the LAYOUTS/ADMIN web.config. Changed that and reset IIS... and I'm golden!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a web.config in Layouts folder. Turn off errors in that file.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460914.aspx

Or you can also turn on developer dashboard which will also show you the stack trace information.

```
$service = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$addsetting =$service.DeveloperDashboardSettings
#Use On Off or OnDemand
$addsetting.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::On
$addsetting.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful : [Troubleshooting SharePoint 2010 : Tools & Techniques](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/25/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-tools-techniques/)